# why does this code for finding if the user input is a number or a char does not work?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include    <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    double number= 0.0;
    n1:
    printf(" Your number:");
    scanf("%lf",&number);
    getchar();
    if(!isdigit(number))
    {
       printf("not a number, please only numbers\n");
       goto n1;
    }
    else
    {
       printf("is a number");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

why doesnt this work?
where did I make a mistake here ?
Is the function `isdigit()` used correctly?

Comment: Did you see the warnings? Did you read the docs of `isdigit`?

Comment: `scanf()` won't put anything into `number` if it's not a valid number.

Comment: Suggestion: mind your compiler diagnostics. Treat them as failures and correct the code before running the executable.

Comment: I don't think jumping back with `goto` instead of using a loop is going to win you many friends.

Comment: @pmg You're assuming there were warnings. Godbolt gave me none , even with `-Wall`.

Comment: Oops... my bad: a `double` value may be silently converted to `int` in some cases.

Comment: @pmg C certainly has a lot of ways to shoot yourself in the foot.